# Matplotlib: multiple stacked graphs in one figure

Tags: python, matplotlib

Simulating the remote control of the dji mavic pro I have a display showing the stick position in a polar plot and its (x, y) values by projecting these on the x and y axis of a Cartesian plot placing the polar plot and the Cartesian plot in the same location using `fig.add_axes(rect)` calculating the correct values for `rect = [left, bottom, width, height]`.

I then make two instances one for the stick on the left and one for the stick on the right, all in one figure.

[image]

The program works, but I wonder if matplotlib has better way of gridding stacked plots?

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import patches as mpl_patches
from matplotlib import lines as mpl_lines

fig_size = (13, 6)
stick_end_color = 'red'
stick_end_size = 5
stick_color = 'blue'
stick_width = 5
bar_color = 'orange'
bar_width = 10

def conv_xy_to_polar(x, y):
    return np.degrees(np.arctan2(y, x)), np.sqrt(x*x + y*y)


class RemoteControlDisplay:
    def __init__(self, rmax):
        self._rmax = rmax
        mpl.rcParams['toolbar'] = 'None'
        self.rc_fig = plt.figure('Remote Control', figsize=fig_size)
        self.rc_fig.suptitle(None)

    def blit(self):
        self.fig.canvas.draw()
        self.fig.canvas.flush_events()

    @property
    def fig(self):
        return self.rc_fig

    @property
    def rmax(self):
        return  self._rmax


class RcStick():

    def __init__(self, fig, rmax, stick_name, left=True):
        rect_carth_offs = 0.050
        rect_polar_offs = 0.075
        tick_intval = 20

        if left:
            rect_carth = [
                rect_carth_offs, rect_carth_offs,
                0.5-rect_carth_offs, 1 - 2*rect_carth_offs
            ]
            rect_polar = [
                rect_carth[0] + 0.5*rect_polar_offs, rect_carth[1] + rect_polar_offs,
                rect_carth[2] - 1*rect_polar_offs, rect_carth[3] - 2*rect_polar_offs
            ]

        else:
            rect_carth = [
                0.25+2*rect_carth_offs, rect_carth_offs,
                1-4*rect_carth_offs, 1 - 2*rect_carth_offs
            ]
            rect_polar = [
                rect_carth[0] + rect_polar_offs, rect_carth[1] + rect_polar_offs,
                rect_carth[2] - 2*rect_polar_offs, rect_carth[3] - 2*rect_polar_offs
            ]

        # place carthesian grid in fig
        ax_carth = fig.add_axes(rect_carth)

        # adjust x, y limits to match the one on the polar plot
        self.bv = rmax * (1-2*rect_carth_offs) / (1-2*rect_carth_offs-2*rect_polar_offs)
        ax_carth.set(
            xlim=(-self.bv, self.bv), ylim=(-self.bv, self.bv), aspect='equal'
        )

        # axis ticks
        ticks = np.arange(0, self.bv, tick_intval)
        ticks = sorted(np.append(-ticks[1:], ticks))
        ax_carth.set_xticks(ticks)
        ax_carth.set_yticks(ticks)

        # place polar grid in carthesian grid
        ax_polar = fig.add_axes(rect_polar, polar=True, frameon=False)
        ax_polar.set_rmax(rmax)

        # display of stick
        self.stick_end = mpl_patches.Circle(
            (0, 0), radius=stick_end_size, fc=stick_end_color,
            transform=ax_polar.transData._b
        )
        self.stick = mpl_lines.Line2D(
            [0, 0], [0, 0], linewidth=stick_width, color=stick_color
        )
        ax_polar.add_patch(self.stick_end)
        ax_polar.add_line(self.stick)
        self.stick_val(0, 0)

        # display of x, y bars
        self.bar_x = mpl_lines.Line2D(
            [0, 0], [0, 0], linewidth=bar_width, color=bar_color, solid_capstyle='butt',
        )
        self.bar_y = mpl_lines.Line2D(
            [0, 0], [0, 0], linewidth=bar_width, color=bar_color, solid_capstyle='butt',
        )
        ax_carth.add_line(self.bar_x)
        ax_carth.add_line(self.bar_y)
        self.bar_val(0, 0)

        ax_carth.set_title(stick_name)
        ax_polar.set_yticklabels([])

    def stick_val(self, x, y):
        theta, r = conv_xy_to_polar(x, y)
        self.stick_end.center = (x, y)
        self.stick.set_data([0, np.radians(theta)], [0, r])

    def bar_val(self, x, y):
        # from (0, -bv) to (x, -bv)
        self.bar_x.set_data([0, x], [-self.bv, -self.bv])
        # from (-bv, 0) to (-bv, y)
        self.bar_y.set_data([-self.bv, -self.bv], [0, y])

    def rc_vals(self, x, y):
        self.stick_val(x, y)
        self.bar_val(x, y)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    rc = RemoteControlDisplay(120)
    rc_left = RcStick(rc.fig, rc.rmax, 'climb/ yaw', left=True)
    rc_right = RcStick(rc.fig, rc.rmax, 'pitch/ roll', left=False)
    rc_left.rc_vals(80, -60)
    rc_right.rc_vals(-30, 50)
    plt.show()
```

Comment: your implementation seems fine to me, although I don't really understand why you need to cartesian axes at all.

Comment: @DizietAsahi, I am unable to find another way to project the polar value (theta, r) on the x, y axes. Let me know if there is a method...

Comment: I fear that when your question basically reads as "I already did it, everything works, but could it be done any better?" it will not gather many answers here. Especially when you look [at the documentation](https://matplotlib.org/3.3.3/tutorials/intermediate/artists.html) and find sentences like: "If you want to create an Axes at an arbitrary location, simply use the add_axes() method" and you're already doing that.